# How can I display 4 buttons in a row in notifications

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

3 Buttons are no problem, but the 4. one isn´t displayed.

Isn´t it possible at all?

Edit:

I´m adding 4 buttons:

```
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.av_previous, "", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, new Intent(context, NotificationPlayerControlReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.av_play, "", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, new Intent(context, NotificationPlayerControlReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.av_next, "", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 4, new Intent(context, NotificationPlayerControlReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.cancel, "", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 5, new Intent(context, NotificationPlayerControlReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
```

The first three buttons are displayed, the last one not

Comment: can you explain your question in deep.

Comment: please read the documentation for addAction

Comment: nothing about my problem